# Asus FX503VD Ubuntu 18.04 touchpad now working

Tags: kernel, 18.04, touchpad, asus

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Kernel 4.18, I have had the touchpad working before but wanted to do  a dual boot so started from scratch.
everything is working except touchpad.
for xinput i get this
Virtual core XTEST pointer
Logitech M570 (the one i am using to do stuff)
ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device (8910) Consumer Control

In the Grub i have this (only way i could get past the black screen, even after the kernel update and Nvidia driver install)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!"

Comment: Instead you can write it: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

Comment: That did the tricked, it is now fixed. Thank you

Comment: I'll post as a answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Asus Notebook too (X510UR). The GRUB statement is not correct to this hardware.

Please update the GRUB statement `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"` and reboot.

I think that will be enough. Good luck.